# Right click&copy images: protection

Tags: images, copyright

I saw there's a Wordpress plugin that prevents people from using right click on text or images, called [WP Protect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-protect/).
I was wondering if there's a way to hardcode it into Wordpress instead of using a plugin.

What I'm worried about is mainly the images. Being able to mark text is perfectly fine with me.

I tried to find tutorials for this, but all I could find was the plugin I mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality is Plugin territory. I strongly believe that the WordPress core team will *never* consider such functionality for WordPress core.

Besides: such functionality is also pointless. Anyone who wants an image badly enough is going to be able to get them. (They can disable javascript thereby defeating the Plugin entirely; they can view source to find and load the imgae SRC URL directly; the browser probably has a copy of the image cached; RSS feeds have the images enclosed or linked; etc.)

Comment: I'm aware of that. It's just going to reduce the abuse - or so I hope. I see. I'll use watermarks anyways ... and I'm giving the plugin a try then. Thanks!! :)